# Create and load iframes 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple webpages I want to load 1 by 1 on one page with `iframe`'s. So it will first load 1 webpage in an iframe, and when, and only when, the webpage has finished loading, it creates a new iframe with the next web page, and again wait for that to load before creating a new iframe and so on...

First I tried with something like this:

```js
$(document).on('load', '#iframe1', function () {
  $('body').append('<iframe src="https://page2.com" id="iframe2"></iframe>');
}

);
$(document).on('load', '#iframe2', function () {
  $('body').append('<iframe src="https://page3.com" id="iframe3"></iframe>');
}

);
```

```html
<iframe src="https://page1.com" id="iframe1"></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work, it will just load them all at the same time, and if I use `$('#iframe2').load` instead of `$(document).on('load', '#iframe2')` it won't work because the iframe was dynamically created.

I've then found this code on StackOverflow, but it does not wait for the other `iframe` to load before loading the next web page:

```
var urls_to_load = ["https://page1.com", "https://page2.com",
                "page3.com"];

            var i = 0;
            function loadIframeAndcheckIfReady() {
                var current_url = urls_to_load[i];
                alert(i);
                frame = document.createElement('iframe');
                document.body.appendChild(frame);
                frame.setAttribute('src', current_url);
                var inter = window.setInterval(function () {
                    if (frame.contentWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
                        window.clearInterval(inter);
                        i++; //Now we have one url more...
                        if (i < urls_to_load.length)
                            loadIframeAndcheckIfReady(); //recursively call the function until i it's iqual to urls_to_load.length
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
            loadIframeAndcheckIfReady();
```

I have also tried with something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
    if ($iframe.length) {
      $iframe.attr('src', url);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  $('#iframe1').ready(function() {
    loadIframe('iframe2', 'https://page2.com');
    $('#iframe2').ready(function() {
      loadIframe('iframe3', 'https://page3.com');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<iframe src="https://page1.com" id="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="" id="iframe2"></iframe>
<iframe src="" id="iframe3"></iframe>
```

But this also loads 'em all with no wait.

Any suggestions?

Comment: its have any error in console.log and tell me all the iframe are visible

Comment: Use `$('#iframe2').load()` instead of `$('#iframe2').ready()`. Or since the newer versions, `.on('load', ... )`.

Comment: No errors, it works, just not like intended, and i don't want all the iframes to load there web page before the one before that has finished loading its page. So iframe1 loads page1 and when done iframe2 loads page2 and when done iframe3 loads page3 and so on... All iframes are visible

Comment: #Shilly your right, why did i start using ready instead of load :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to #Shilly i learned that i should use .load() instead of .ready()

```
  $('#iframe1').load(function() {
    loadIframe('iframe2', 'https://page2.com');
    $('#iframe2').load(function() {
      loadIframe('iframe3', 'https://page3.com');
    });
  });
```